# Java based FB.init

Tags: facebook, graph, authentication

Is there a way to process the FB.init function within plain java code ?

I have added an inline frame based up, that sends a signed_request param to my server.

The signed_request already covers a good bunch of information.

Due to the fact, that the session_key and the secret are required, I have to display the Facebook login button and let the user click it in order to set the fbs_ cookie.

Any idea how to get completely rid of the login button ?

Answer (score 0):

Java is a server-side programming language, while JavaScript is client-side. Therefore, if you intend to use the FB JavaScript library, you need to embed this in your webpage. This is pretty straightforward with frameworks like Wicket for instance. However, no matter you embed the JavaScript at server side, it'll get executed when it gets downloaded and invoked in the user's browser.